# Looping through data subsets to generate additional plots in R

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, subset

(apologies for the non-standard R, I'm new to it)

I have an array of colors that my data is formatted with:

```
colors <- c("red", "blue", "orange", "turquoise4", "green3")
```

I'm generating a plot that is organized by colour/Party:

```
main_aes = aes(x = Date, y = Popular_Support, colour=Party, size=1/Error, weight=1/Error)
plot <- ggplot(polls) 
plot2 <- plot + geom_point(main_aes)
plot2 <- plot2 + scale_colour_manual(values = colors)
```

to which I add a trendline:

```
plot_smooth <- plot2 + stat_smooth(data=polls, span = .35)
```

I <del>want a different trend and ribbon for each color</del>, need to manipulate the smoothed data before plotting it, so I extract the smoothed data:

```
smooth_data <- ggplot_build(plot_smooth)$data[[2]]
# do some custom manipulations of smooth_data here
```

Then I manually create the individual trends and confidence ribbons.  **It is this part I'm looking for help using loops instead of repetitive code:**

```
party_trend.1 <- subset(smooth_data, colour == colors[1])
party_trend.2 <- subset(smooth_data, colour == colors[2])
party_trend.3 <- subset(smooth_data, colour == colors[3])
party_trend.4 <- subset(smooth_data, colour == colors[4])
party_trend.5 <- subset(smooth_data, colour == colors[5])

plot <- plot + geom_ribbon(data = party_trend.1, aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax = ymax), alpha = .25)
plot <- plot + geom_ribbon(data = party_trend.2, aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax = ymax), alpha = .25)
plot <- plot + geom_ribbon(data = party_trend.3, aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax = ymax), alpha = .25)
plot <- plot + geom_ribbon(data = party_trend.4, aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax = ymax), alpha = .25)
plot <- plot + geom_ribbon(data = party_trend.5, aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax = ymax), alpha = .25)

plot <- plot + geom_line(data = party_trend.1, colour=colors[1], aes(x = x, y = y))
plot <- plot + geom_line(data = party_trend.2, colour=colors[2], aes(x = x, y = y))
plot <- plot + geom_line(data = party_trend.3, colour=colors[3], aes(x = x, y = y))
plot <- plot + geom_line(data = party_trend.4, colour=colors[4], aes(x = x, y = y))
plot <- plot + geom_line(data = party_trend.5, colour=colors[5], aes(x = x, y = y))
```

I assume if I can create an array for the party_trend, the other 2 loops will be easy, I tried something like this:

```
party_trend <- 0
for(i in colors) {
    party_trend[i] <- subset(smooth_data, colour == colors[i])
}
```

But I can't figure out how to create/initialize the party_trend array before using it here.  This gives me the error:

Warning messages:

```
1: In party_trend[i] <- subset(smooth_data, colour == colors[i]) :   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length 
2: In party_trend[i] <- subset(smooth_data, colour == colors[i]) :   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
3...5
```

Here's a [working fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=0UNj2rov&version=33)

**EDIT FOR CONTEXT**
This is not relevant to the looping question, but might help explain why I'm not just using the default plot.  The reason I am extracting the data and re plotting manually is because sometimes I want the trend and ribbon to use data that will not be plotted.  So I used the default calculation from the entire data set, extract it, trim it, and only plot the part I want.  This is not happening in this specific fiddle (though you can see remnants on line 107-8), but you can see the results [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Opinion_Polling_during_the_2015_Canadian_Federal_Election.svg).  Notice how the beginning of the plot does have the characteristic "trumpet" shape, because the trend is using more data than is actually being displayed, that continues to the left.

Comment: Hi, it is hard to tell without knowing the shape of data. Could you provide some reproducible example?

Comment: It seems like you're doing this a bit backwards. If your goal is to create individual and uniquely colored plots for each party, create a loop that goes through the parties, and inside that loop, create a plot using the appropriate subset of the data. Should be simpler than creating a plot with all parties and then trying to extract each one individually.

Comment: Providing data will help. Are you trying to make separate charts - 1 for each color, each chart with points and  a trendline?

Comment: Thanks folks, I added a link to a working fiddle.

Comment: I imagine I'm missing something, but is the normal  `ggplot(election_polls,
       aes(x = Date, 
           y = Popular_Support, 
           colour = Party, 
           size=1/Error, 
           weight=1/Error)
) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(span = 0.35)` a step in the right direction? `colour` in the `aes` defines an implicit grouping which handles the "loop" for you.

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything.  I'm just a hack, coding in the penumbra of lucidity...

Comment: Ok, I remembered why I'm doing it the way I'm doing it and tried to add an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create a line and a ribbon for each level of `Party` you don't need to create them individually with. You can put the factors in `ggplot(data=polls, aes(x=Date, y=Popular_Support, color=Party))` and then call `geom_smooth()`:

```
plot <- ggplot(data=polls,
               aes(x=Date, y=Popular_Support, color=Party)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth()
```

So you can remove that:

```
#Do this in a loop!!!!
party_trend <- 0
for(i in colors) {
  party_trend[i] <- subset(smooth_data, colour == colors[i])
}

party_trend.1 <- subset(smooth_data, colour == colors[1])
party_trend.2 <- subset(smooth_data, colour == colors[2])
party_trend.3 <- subset(smooth_data, colour == colors[3])
party_trend.4 <- subset(smooth_data, colour == colors[4])
party_trend.5 <- subset(smooth_data, colour == colors[5])

plot <- plot + geom_ribbon(data = party_trend.1, aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax = ymax), alpha = .25)
plot <- plot + geom_ribbon(data = party_trend.2, aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax = ymax), alpha = .25)
plot <- plot + geom_ribbon(data = party_trend.3, aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax = ymax), alpha = .25)
plot <- plot + geom_ribbon(data = party_trend.4, aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax = ymax), alpha = .25)
plot <- plot + geom_ribbon(data = party_trend.5, aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax = ymax), alpha = .25)
plot <- plot + geom_line(data = party_trend.1, colour=colors[1], aes(x = x, y = y))
plot <- plot + geom_line(data = party_trend.2, colour=colors[2], aes(x = x, y = y))
plot <- plot + geom_line(data = party_trend.3, colour=colors[3], aes(x = x, y = y))
plot <- plot + geom_line(data = party_trend.4, colour=colors[4], aes(x = x, y = y))
plot <- plot + geom_line(data = party_trend.5, colour=colors[5], aes(x = x, y = y))

#print(plot)
plot <- plot + scale_colour_manual(values = colors)
plot <- plot +  geom_point(main_aes, alpha=0.8)
```

Finally you can add your other plot features:

```
plot <- plot + scale_colour_manual(values = colors)
plot <- plot +  geom_point(main_aes, alpha=0.8)

plot <- plot +   scale_size_area(max_size=3, breaks=seq(20,60,10), labels=seq(20,60,10)^2, name="Sample Size") 
plot <- plot +   guides(color = guide_legend(order=-1) )
  #last election                                 
plot <- plot + geom_point(data=LastElection, size=3, shape=5, show_guide= F, main_aes) 
plot <- plot + geom_point(data=LastElection, size=2, show_guide=F, main_aes) 
plot <- plot + geom_text(data=LastElection, show_guide=F, 
            aes(x = Date, y = Popular_Support, label = Popular_Support), size=3, hjust=-.2, vjust=-0.4)
# this election
#plot <- plot + geom_point(data=ThisElection, size=3, shape=5, show_guide=F, main_aes) +
#  geom_point(data=ThisElection, size=2, show_guide=F, main_aes) +
#  geom_text(data=ThisElection, show_guide=F, 
#            aes(x = Date, y = Popular_Support, label = Popular_Support), size=3, hjust=-.2, vjust=-0.4)

plot <- plot + scale_x_continuous(name = "Date", limits=c(42291,43759), minor_breaks = seq(42291, 43759, by=30),breaks = seq(42291, 43759, by=90))
                                  #minor_breaks = seq(42216, 42296, by=1), breaks = seq(42291, 43759, by=90))
plot <- plot + scale_y_continuous(name = "% Popular Support", lim=c(0,56), expand=c(0,0)) 
plot <- plot + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 11, vjust=.5, angle = 90, colour="#333333"))
plot <- plot + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())
plot <- plot + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 11))
plot <- plot + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 11, angle = 90, colour="#333333"))
#theme(legend.justification=c(1,1), legend.position=c(1,1))
```

**UPDATE**:

You can use another dataframe in `geom_smooth()`. Here is a minimal example showing a case where the line and ribbon are calculated and plotted from another dataframe than the data points:

```
n <- rnorm(100, mean=0, sd=1)
dat <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=n, lab=c(rep('a', 50), rep('b', 50)))

n1 <- rnorm(100, mean=2, sd=1)
dat1 <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=n1, lab=c(rep('a', 50), rep('b', 50)))

ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(data=dat1)
```

giving:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I added additional context as to why I'm doing it the way I'm doing it.

Comment: @43Tesseracts You can use another dataframe in `geom_smooth()`. You have to add the corresponding `data` and `aes` if there are different: `geom_smooth(data=otherDf, aes(...))`. See my update.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't really answer my question.  I already have all this working, I just want to know how to put that section of code into a loop!

Comment: @43Tesseracts Sorry I think I don't understand. You don't need a loop if you have data in another dataframe (`R` is also better at vector operations...)